# PJSIP for iOS 6 under Xcode 4.5 (armv7 & armv7s)

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, armv7, pjsip

I update Xcode from 4.4.1 to 4.5. Now all my projects using PJSIP are
crashed. Anyone help me compiling PJSIP for Xcode 4.5?
Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in version 4.5 the support for armv6 was removed and by default the support for armv7s is enabled. you have to compile the library first with armv7 support and then with armv7s support and then you have to merge this into a one fat library using lipo.

Steps:

```
# ARCH="-arch armv7" ./configure-iphone 
# make dep && make
```

then you can collect your libraries into a folder and add the armv7 part to the library names

then do you have to clean and rebuild again with armv7s support

```
# make clean
# ARCH="-arch armv7s" ./configure-iphone 
# make dep && make
```

copy all of the libraries into the same folder with the previous ones and add the armv7s part to the library names. Then you can use lip to combine the libraries into a single library like this:

```
# lipo -output libgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a -create libgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9-armv7.a libgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9-armv7s.a
```

you can write a script to automate this or you have to do this manually for every library.

Comment: Do you know how to add it to XCode "Run Script" phase, so that we don't have to run the commands separate.

Comment: @Satyamsvv unfortunately not :(